# If I attain a Master's degree, how do I refer to myself?

Tags: grammaticality

This is in reference to holding an MLS degree. Am I a "Master"? Would it be correct to say

> When I become a Master of Library Science, I would like to...

That sounds somehow kooky, but I can't think of a better way to say it.

Comment: I certainly _wouldn't_ say "When I become a Masters of Library Science", that just sounds ridiculous.

Comment: No. To be a master, you have to catch all 150 pokemon.

Comment: yeah, I guess I'm older than you - I was thinking of He-man.

Comment: I didn't even know they offered degrees in "The Universe"

Comment: Unless you are a girl, and then it's Mistress of Library Sciences!

Comment: You become a *Libratorr*. http://www.penny-arcade.com/comic/2007/08/03

Comment: @JordaanMylonas: They do, but it's not much fun: http://xkcd.com/863/

Comment: "When I graduate as Master of Library Science..."

Comment: My understanding was the the title Is 'MISTER' or 'MISSES' and the formal title is never abbreviated in an address to be confused with lay* people's 'Mr' and 'Mrs'. *Sorry, can't thin kof a better way to put it off-hand.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes. If you graduate with a BSc or BA, you *are* a Bachelor of Science or a Bachelor of Arts respectively. Similarly if you graduate with a master's, you are a master, and if you graduate with a doctorate you're a doctor.

But it's almost unheard of nowadays for people to routinely refer to themselves by their academic title for qualifications lower than doctorate level (and that's becoming rarer too in my experience), so something like "After I graduate with my master's, I would like to..." might be better.

Comment: It's not unusual for people who have doctorates.

Comment: This may be technically correct, but it's misleading, given that in modern usage (as Dan indicated) those with doctorates are commonly referred to with special honorifics, whereas those with master's or bachelor's degrees never --at least within my experience --are.  I do realize you called it "fairly unusual" but I don't think that goes far enough.  (Note: My experience is with American usage, perhaps it is different in the UK or other English-speaking countries.)

Comment: @ChrisSunami You're totally correct - it's just an example of classic British understatement. I'll amend the answer.

Comment: I remember at least in german there is a difference between holding a degree (bachelor, master, diploma) and a title (doctorate). For historic reasons, the doctorate level gives you a title, but everything else is a degree or a status (professor is also quite often not regarded as a title).

Answer (score 5):

What about simply:

> When I receive an/my/the MSL degree, I would like to ...

Comment: Thanks. That _does_ work... but I guess I would like the text to a little more punchy/personal. To my ear, "becoming" something sounds more dramatic than "receiving" something.

Comment: More than one PhD has been started because of that.

Comment: @JMCCreative  When I *earn* or *achieve*, then.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of "When I become a Master of Library Science, I would like to..." you could write, "As a Master of Library Science, I will..." (or "will want to" instead of "will") or could write "When I attain my advanced degree...".

For advice on writing in "punchy/personal/dramatic" modes, post questions in [writers.stackexchange.com](https://writers.stackexchange.com/), where such questions are more on topic than here in ESE.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid you don't become anything after obtaining a master's degree other than "Someone who has a Master's." When this is relevant, you say "I have my Master's in ". To talk about it in the future, you'd say "After I get my master's, I would like to..."

Comment: Obtaining a master's degree in a field, particularly one with practical applications, an internship, etc.  you do become something. You become credentialed for  attaining a defined level of expertise. I remember laughing with my friends when we were graduated with Master of Science in Engineering degrees, saying, "I am now a MASTER of Science", though we didn't feel like the master of ANYTHING then! But in a letter to a prospective employer, or an application essay for graduate work, it is necessary to use this sort of stilted language.

Comment: +1 - When I got mine, I tried to tell my wife and kids that my title was now "Master". I can assure you, it did not fly.