# Am I a graduate or a Masters graduate?

Tags: word-choice

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [If I attain a Master’s degree, how do I refer to myself?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45092/if-i-attain-a-masters-degree-how-do-i-refer-to-myself)

I am writing a Personal Statement on a CV and a lot of the samples have 'Graduate with experience in...' this, I believe, implies a BA or similar level of degree. What do you put when referring to a Masters Degree?

Comment: If it is the CV, better to avoid 'Graduate' altogether -- it means different things to different people (in different places). Say *Bachelors (Degree)* / *Masters (Degree)* to be clear.

Comment: Visit ESL http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners

Answer (score 3):

There area  couple of options:

- It's quite common to say "I have a masters [degree] in XYZ" for an M.A. or M.S., with the "degree" being optional.
- For more specific degrees like an MBA or an MFA (periods optional in those), you would refer to the degree itself, "I have an MBA from Hahvard."
- You can also use the degree abbreviation, M.A. or M.S:  "I have an M.A. in English from Hogwarts State University."
- For more formality, use the full title: "I have a Master of Arts degree from FooBar University."

Note that it's capitalized when you are referring to the specific degree, but not when you are referring to it generically.  So, "I have a Master of Arts degree" but "I have a master's degree".

Answer (score 2):

In British English, we often use the word, `Postgraduate`, to describe `someone who is studying at a university to get a Master's Degree or a PhD`.

Answer (score 1):

You may simply call yourself a Master of Arts (or of Sciences, or of Social Work, etc.) with experience in...etc.

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/master+of+arts